# How to upgrade datadog collector agent?

Tags: logging, version, upgrade, monitoring, datadog

Iam using a puppetized datadog agent install(version 1.10.0), and looks like i'm on default dd-agent version - 5.9.1. Would like to upgrade. I dont see any docs related to that. Can someone point me on how to do this?

Comment: Hmm, you're using [this](https://github.com/DataDog/puppet-datadog-agent), right? I was under the impression that the puppet module for datadog would just install whatever is the most recent version of the dd-agent. Maybe your puppet is using old repos rather than updating?

Comment: Yes, i m using that. But unfortunately - even though i'm at puppet version of 1.10.0 - my dd-agent is still at 5.9.1

Comment: @stephenlechner - any hint?